# gulpfile.babel.js does not compile imported es6 modules from node_modules

Tags: gulp, babeljs

"dev-tools" is lib which has gulp task and "CAPP" imports the tasks from "dev-tools" module in gulpfile.babel.js when I run the gulp build it shows below error:

```
C:\projects\app\CAPP>gulp build
[22:29:54] Requiring external module babel-register
C:\projects\app\CAPP\node_modules\dev-tools\index.js:6
import config from './tasks/config';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
at Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```

There is a same question is on gulp issue

Comment: What are your `.eslintrc` settings?

Comment: This is expected behavior, the assumption is that `node_modules` will have been transpiled before being published to npm. You'd need to manually load and configure `babel-register` on your own for it to do this.